# Open default SMS app in Android Oreo

Tags: android, sms, android-8.0-oreo

I am not able to open the default SMS app in Android Oreo.
I used this code for older releases:

```
   Intent oIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   oIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
   oIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList");
   startActivityForResult(oIntent, 12345);
```

It has been working well. But with Oreo I am getting this error:

> Unable to find explicit activity class
>   {com.android.mms/com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList}; have you
>   declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Now with Oreo, I think, the user could select the default messaging app. So, is there a way to get which is that app by code?
Then I would only need to do this:

```
String sPackageManager = GetDefaultMessagingApp(); <-- This is what I need

Intent oIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(sPackageManager);
startActivity(oIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I used this code for older releases

That code has nothing to do with "open[ing] the default SMS app". That attempts to start a specific activity (`com.android.mms.ui.ConversationList`) in a specific app (`com.android.mms`). Of note:

- There is no requirement for the device to have that app
- There is no requirement for that app to have that activity, across all versions of that app
- There is no requirement that the user has set this to be their default SMS client
- There is no requirement that the user wants to use this SMS client, even if it is not the default

[Call `Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Telephony.Sms.html#getDefaultSmsPackage(android.content.Context)) on Android 4.4+ to find out what the user has chosen as their default SMS client.